# Object is not visible in the rendering tab and within the rendered scene but visible in the animation tab

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've just started to use Blender and I am trying to add a 3D object to the video scene with Blender. The default tutorial was ok and everything worked out with the default 3d monkey mesh. Then I downloaded a random 3D model from the web and tried to add it using the same steps but now this model is not showing up during rendering. I can see it in the animation tab though.

[Blend file](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/TPphA3wo#link)

Animation tab:
[image]

Rendering tab (and renders as well):
[image]

What can I do to figure out the reason here?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? (Only keep the useful objects)